# How to get the value from variable in switch statement is javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var day = "Sunday";
var x;

switch (day) {
  case 0:
    var x = 5;
    day = "Sunday";
    break;
  case 1:
    day = "Monday";
    break;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Today is " + day + " " + x;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

I want to get output as Today is Sunday 5

but I am getting the output as Today is Sunday undefined

How can get the value as 5 instead of undefined???

Comment: You are missing an assignment to x in the case 1 branch. Please read up on the working of the switch statement.

Comment: The assignment of x is completely irrelevant, it is not being used and does not correlate to the fact that the output is undefined. The reason the output is undefined is because the case is expecting a type of int when it is being passed a string into the switch. Therefore, it would usually hit the default case, but since there isnt one - undefined is returned.

Comment: `switch(day)` means your cases are checked against `day`. Your code would only make sense if `day` had a value of `0` or  `1`.

Answer (score 1):

it is because of mistake in switch statement you are using number instead of day

like case 0: instead of  case "sunday"
that is the mistake

```js
var day = "Sunday";
var x;

switch (day) {
  case "Sunday":
    var x = 5;
    day = "Sunday";
    break;
  case "Monday":
    day = "Monday";
    break;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Today is " + day + " " + x;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

you can try like this too *with numbers*

> The getDay() method returns the weekday as a number between 0 and 6.
>
> (Sunday=0, Monday=1, Tuesday=2 ..)

This example uses the weekday number to calculate the weekday name:

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var day;
var x=0;
switch (new Date().getDay()) {
    case 0:
        day = "Sunday";
        break;
    case 1:
   
        day = "Monday";
        break;
    case 2:
        day = "Tuesday";
        break;
    case 3:
        day = "Wednesday";
        break;
    case 4:
        day = "Thursday";
        break;
    case 5:
        day = "Friday";
        break;
    case  6:
        day = "Saturday";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Today is " + day + x;
</script>
```

> How can get the value as 5 instead of undefined???

variable in javascript will be initialized to undefined .so is out puts undefined because it didn't set to 5 in switch case (fails in condition to assing)

Comment: This is exactly what I said in my answer and I got down voted wtaf!

Comment: There's no need to set day again in the `switch`, and no need to use `var` in the switch either.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is pretty simple:

```
switch (day) {
 case 0:
var x = 5;
day = "Sunday";
break;
case 1:
day = "Monday";
break;
}
```

In the above code `switch(day)` you are passing a string "Sunday " and **in cases matching it with an int type** like `case 0`,it is not possible so try to pass an int in switch() or use case like `case "Sunday"`:

```
 switch (day) {
 case "Sunday":
var x = 5;
day = "Sunday";
break;
case "anyday"://use case as you want
day = "anyday";
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find it easier to use an object to hold a set of keys/values. You can then check the object using the value held in `day`.

```js
const days = {
  sunday: 5,
  monday: 2
};

let day = "Sunday";

const demo = document.getElementById('demo');
demo.innerHTML = "Today is " + day + " " + days[day.toLowerCase()];
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```